# I don't understand these simple sentences. Please help me

Tags: meaning

What do these sentences mean:

> Please note that this is not proof that the abovementioned amount has been credited to your account on the action date reflected above. 
>   Payment may take up to three business days to be reflected on your account.

I'm not a native English speaker. I cannot understand, especially 'action date' and 'to be reflected on your account'. Action date means sort of deadline?

Comment: It means that you cannot use the message you received as evidence that your account was credited on the date reflected. It may take more time. But it sounds like it will be credited. It just may take up to three days. If you don't see the credit within three days, you should contact the bank or other entity that sent you the message.

Comment: If you deposit a check (cheque) into your account today (2016-09-21), then you will probably be able to get a statement from your bank (or whatever) that shows a deposit on 2016-09-21.  That will be the "action date".  But, if you go in to the bank tomorrow or the next day and try to withdraw the money, you may (probably will) be told that it's not there.  You will need to wait until 2016-09-24 for the actual balance in your account to be the same as what the statement says ("reflect" is used somewhat idiomatically to mean "show the same thing").

Comment: (Compare to a person walking through your dressing room. Depending on your relative locations, he may need to take three steps (after you first see him with your eyes) before you see him *reflected* in the mirror.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is some sort of service message from a payment service or bank.

> Please note that this is not proof that the abovementioned amount has been credited to your account on the action date reflected above.

"this" (whatever it is, some message I assume) simply notifies you that you were credited (given) some amount of money. "Action Date" probably means the date that the request was made. For example the date that the sender of the money confirmed the transaction.

> Payment may take up to three business days to be reflected on your account.

It could take up to three business days before you see the change on your account. This means that even though the transaction may have been processed already, it will take some time until you can see it.